# Adding a C/C++ nature to an Eclipse project

Tags: c, eclipse, project

Does anybody know how to add a C/C++ project nature to an Eclipse project through the UI ?
I'm importing a project and working with legacy code that was originally started in Visual Studio 4 and I'd really like to be able to make as much use of Eclipse's helpers as possible.

Comment: you can check this link  http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-development/

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Assuming you've got the CDT plugin installed

Right-click on the project.

Select: New -> Other

Under C/C++, select "Convert to a C/C++ project"

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for Glen, thank you kindly for your answer.

Comment: In the current version, they've improved the menu item so it now reads "Convert to a C/C++ project (Adds C/C++ Nature)"

Comment: Just a note: this feature works exactly as advertised: it *Adds* C/C++ Nature to a project.  Which turned out to work great for my Java project which also includes JNI C++ code, allowing it to also keep it's existing Java nature.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new C project using the existing source code.