# Code-completion / Project type in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, svn, subversive

I have a project which is under SVN source control. I can easily set up Subversive for Eclipse, connect to the repository and check out the code. Once I've done this (from the SVN perspective) it appears just fine as a project in the C++/C perspective.

The problem is, eclipse doesn't seem to recognise it as a C++ project which means the code-completion is not functioning. Since it created the project automatically upon checking out the code I didn't get the option to tell it it was dealing with C++. Is there a way to specify to eclipse that this is the case?

Bonus Q: (More personal preference than anything) Under source control we actually have two sets of code (they work together). Would you check out these two subfolders into separate eclipse projects or just work with it as they are?

Comment: Look to be same issue as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323107/adding-a-c-c-nature-to-an-eclipse-project), and you could also modify the .project file in the project directly to add the nature.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for this, if you'd have posted it as an answer I could have accepted it :)

Also, any thoughts on the bonus question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided the answer in the comment.  For the bonus question, I'd check out the subfolders into separate projects, sort of how I would do when developing Eclipse plugins.