# Importing C Eclipse Project into Perforce

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, perforce

I have the Perforce plug-In in my Eclipse IDE. Now I want to import Eclipse C projects that is already in the Perforce server. However, I cannot build them. They do not get imported as a C project.

Answer (score 0):

I observed the same situation for Java project. Looks like any project from perforce is imported as just the Project. So that to resolve the problem I used the following approach.

1. Create project from perforce
2. Create separate language-specific project and  set it up so that it is created from existing sources.
3. Share project (in perforce plugin terminology) so this is under perforce control now

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by create project from Perforce??

Comment: Press ctrl+N and choose "project from perforce". Then select the branch you're going to consider as the project.

Comment: That key doesn't work for me. Also, in the File menu of Perforce I do not have this option.. I use p4v Perforce Visual Client/LINUX26X86/2010.2/317255

Comment: All those actions I was talking about should be performed inside of Eclipse IDE. So then in your case you should right-click on the required branch (holding your project) and choose sync to head revision. Notice where it is stored on your HDD. Then proceed from step 2 by specifying sources of that synced project (just point the folder perforceput your project to)

Comment: Thanks Alexey. But I have a problem that when I try to build any perforce projects, I have no permissions: This is the error I got:Problems occurred building the selected resources.
Errors running builder 'CDT Builder' on project 'proj1'.
Could not write to read-only file: '/proj1/Debug/sources.mk'.
Could not write to read-only file: '/proj1/Debug/sources.mk'.

Comment: Ok I checked this post which had lot of information. The only conclusion is the files are always read-only :( Also, I do not see how I can import projects from other eclipse workspaces to the eclipse-perforce workspace and check it in each time... Check this link: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/206273/

Answer (score 0):

In my Eclipse, I can right click on the project and choose New --> "Convert to a C/C++ project (Adds C/C++ Nature)". See also this question: [Adding a C/C++ nature to an Eclipse project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323107/adding-a-c-c-nature-to-an-eclipse-project)